# deserializing nested array of values using Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a json file that contains a nested array of values:

```
[
    {"target": "dsdsa", 
     "datapoints": 
        [
            [94.283, 1435080720], 
            [94.233, 1435080780], 
            ....
        ]
     }
]
```

I'm having problem parsing inner nested arrays. I'm using Spring and Jackson. I first parse the outer array using:

```
Output[] allJson = restTemplate.getForObject("json/url",Output[].class);
```

where Output is a POJO:

```
public class Output
{
    public String target;
    //public Datapoint[] datapoints;
}   

public class Datapoint 
{
    private double[] points;
}
```

Using this I can access the "target" from the json. But if I uncomment it, Jackson is not able to map the array of array of values to the Datapoints.

Do I need another wrapper class? 
I couldn't find any example where inside the array there is anything except json objects and Jackson parses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[94.283, 1435080720]` inside datapoints is not a json object but it's a json list. You will have to use two dimentional array or a list within a list for datapoints. Use

`public double[][] datapoints;` or `List<List<Double>> datapoints`