# Parsing nested JSON Arrays using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Im using jacson to parse the following JSON array

```
[
  {
"target": "something",
"datapoints": [
  [
  null,
  1482223380
  ]]}]
```

Into this POJO

```
public class Response {

  private String target;
  private List<List<Double>> datapoints;

  public String getTarget() {
    return target;
  }

  public void setTarget(String target) {
    this.target = target;
  }

  public List<List<Double>> getData() {
    return datapoints;
  }

  public void setData(List<List<Double>> data) {
    this.datapoints = data;
  }
}
```

Using the following code

```
objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Response>>() {});
```

This works partially, the `outer list` and the `target` is correct, however `datapoints` is null.

My initial solution is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059374/deserializing-nested-array-of-values-using-jackson) answere.

My question is, why are not `datapoints` not parsed as expected? Do this has something todo with the null values inside the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom `JsonDeserializer` for the `datapoints` field.

```
class MyDatapointsDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<List<Double>>> {

    private static final TypeReference<List<List<Double>>> TYPE_REF = 
            new TypeReference<List<List<Double>>>() {};

    @Override
    public List<List<Double>> deserialize(
            JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return jp.readValueAs(TYPE_REF);
    }
}
```

Then annotate the field accordingly.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDatapointsDeserializer.class)
private List<List<Double>> datapoints;
```